# using Linux cut, sort and uniq

Tags: linux, sorting, cut, uniq

I have a list with population, year, and county and I need to cut the list, and then find the number of uniq counties.

The list starts off like this:

```
#Population,    Year,   County
3900,   1969,   Beaver
3798,   1970,   Beaver
3830,   1971,   Beaver
3864,   1972,   Beaver
3993,   1973,   Beaver
3976,   1974,   Beaver
4064,   1975,   Beaver
```

There is much more to this list, and many more counties. I have to cut out the county column, sort it, and then output the number of uniq counties. I tried this command:

```
 cut -c3- list.txt | sort -k3 | uniq -c
```

But this does not cut the third list, nor does it sort it alphabetically. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can add a delimiter, which is a comma in your case:

```
cut -f 3 -d, list.txt | sort | uniq
```

then, `-c` specifies *character* position, rather than field, which is specified with `-f`.

To strip spaces in front you can pipe this all through, e.g. `awk '{print $1}'`, i.e.

```
cut -f 3 -d, list.txt | awk '{print $1}' | sort | uniq
```

[edit]

Aaaaand. If you try to `cut` the 3rd field out, you are left with only one field after the pipe, so sorting on the 3rd field won't work, which is why I omitted it in my example. You get 1 field, you just sort on it and the apply `uniq`.

Comment: Cool this works thank you. If I wanted to print the line numbers with the result how would I do that?

Comment: in the `awk` version, you could directly output the third field (ie, no need of `cut` step)...

Comment: @user2615699 not sure what you ask for... try to add `|cat -n`

Answer (score 4):

You can use awk to extract third field (space delimited), and then do your sort/uniq stuff.

```
awk '{print $3}' list.txt |sort |uniq -c
```