# How to list or cat files sorted numerically?

Tags: cat, ls

I have the following files:

> 1A34_3_2.pdb
> 1A34_6_3.pdb
> 1A34_9_4.pdb
> 1A34_A_5.pdb
> 1A34_D_6.pdb
> ...
> 1A34_A2_23.pdb
> ...
> 1A34_BK_45.pdb

I would like to sort them numerically, based on the numbers at the end of file name [e.g., "6" is the number at the end of file name 1A34_D_6.pdb]

If I use `ls -1v 1A34*`, the result is:

> 1A34_3_2.pdb
> 1A34_6_3.pdb
> 1A34_9_4.pdb
> 1A34_A2_23.pdb
> 1A34_A_5.pdb
> 1A34_BK_45.pdb
> 1A34_D_6.pdb

This is not in ascending order of last number in the file name.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21584727/using-linux-cut-sort-and-uniq

Answer (score 0):

Please feed the output of `ls` command to this filter:

```
ls | perl -e '@filenames=<>; print sort {substr($a, 7) <=> substr($b, 7)} @filenames'
```

Output:

```
1A34_3_2.pdb
1A34_6_3.pdb
1A34_9_4.pdb
1A34_A_5.pdb
1A34_D_6.pdb
1A34_9_14.pdb
1A34_D_16.pdb
```

`@filenames=<>;` slurps the output of `ls` command into the array `@filenames`.

`sort()`'s `@filenames` numerically, starting at the 7th offset of the string to be sorted, for example 1A34_3_**2.pdb**:  `sort {substr($a, 7) <=> substr($b, 7)} @filenames`

References:
[sort()](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sort)
[substr()](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/substr)